# Resume from suspend only works with external monitor

Tags: suspend, amd-graphics

Since I upgraded from Xubuntu 22.04 to Xubuntu 23.04 (currently on 23.10), my Lenovo laptop has problems with waking from `pm-suspend`:

- When the external monitor is connected, it *always* works.
- With the laptop on its own, it randomly works *sometimes*, but most of the time the screen is just blank and I need to reboot. There is no apparent pattern to when it works and when it doesn't, except that the laptop having been suspend for a longer time makes it less likely to resume.

What might be going on here? I've found a number of other problem descriptions online, but none seems to match mine exactly.

Kernel:

```
root@exobrain ~# uname -r
6.5.0-14-generic
```

Graphics:

```
root@exobrain ~# lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Barcelo
    [..]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Sleep state:

```
root@exobrain ~# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]
```

I have also tried to use `s2idle`, but this doesn't work at all, the system just hangs without suspending.

Comment: I've upgraded the kernel to 6.7.1 using ``mainline install-latest`` and for now it's working. Still, I'd be interested in further suggestions about how to troubleshoot this.